# Send a message to the connected user using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I have some trouble to understand how to send a message using `socket.io` to the user who is doing an HTML request.

More explainations:

## Server

My server is `expressJS` and I use `router.get` and `router.post` to manage all my application.
I use cookie-session (https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) also.

## Client

The client must login first, then he is redirected on a single page application, everything is handle with AJAX.

## Real-time notifications

I would like to let the client to do an AJAX request for exemple, and send a notification using `socket.io`.

## Server-side code

- `app.js`

```js
// Require all modules first, then:
var server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(443);
io = io().listen(server, {
  wsEngine: 'ws',     // Use "ws" engine (otherwise: seg. fault)
  pingInterval: 3000, // Time in ms to send a ping paquet
  pingTimeout: 3000,  // Time ins ms to set a connection as disconnected
  allowUpgrades: false,
  cookie: false
});
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.io) req.io = io;
  if (!req.sockets) req.sockets = {};
  next();
});
```

- index route (`index.js`)

```js
router.get('/home', function (req, res, next) {
  req.io.emit('logged', 'Hello!');

  // Some data processing
  // ...
  //
  
  res.render('home/home', { datas: datas, csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
});
```

## Client-side code

- index page

```html
<html>

<!-- page content -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  // Import socket.io functions
  var socket = io.connect({
    reconnection: true,
    reconnectionDelay: 1000,
    reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,
    reconnectionAttempts: Infinity
  });
</script>
<script src="/static/js/socket.io-management.js"></script>

</html>
```

- `socket.io-management.js`

```js
socket.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('socket connected');
});
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  console.log('socket disconnected');
});
socket.on('error', function () {
  console.log('socket error');
});

socket.on('logged', function (msg) {
  if ((msg !== 'undefined') && (msg !== null)) console.log(msg);
  else console.log('Logged');
});
```

## The problem

On the server, `req.io.emit('logged', 'Hello!');` is working, but send this message to all users, not the one who request the page.

How can I send this message to only this specific user? I have tried lot of stuff untill now, without success.

Answer (score 0):

you can send to specific user using `socketId`

```
req.io.sockets.connected[socketid].emit('logged', 'Hello!');
```

Comment: I tried it, but I need to get the correct socket id per user, and I did NOT succeed it